# JAVA: Does parent object that initilized with child class has access to variable in child

Tags: java

In here, if we have Parent and Child class

```
class Parent {
    int A = 0;

    void say() {
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int A = 1;
    int B = 3;

    void say() {
        System.out.println(A+B);
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why obj.A gives me 0 but obj.say has A as 1?

```
    Parent obj = new Child();
    System.out.println(obj.A); //print 0
    obj.say();  //print 4
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's basic question. And just running it in ay IDE would give answer.

Comment: @GauravJeswani sorry about that, edited the question and now I am even more confused after running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance can be slightly confusing when declaring a parent class with a sub-class instance.

Essentially, methods can override, while fields cannot.

So, this prints *0* because *obj* is a *Parent* object.

```java
System.out.println(obj.A); //print 0
```

And, this prints 4 because *say* has been overridden, and *obj* was instantiated as a *Child* object.

```java
obj.say();  //print 4
```

Another way to look at it is, you were expecting this as the result, of assigning field *A*, in *Child*.

```java
int A = (super.A = 1);
```

Here is the tutorial Oracle offers, in regard to the topic of *inheritance*.
*[Inheritance (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)*.

And, here is a relevant excerpt.

> *"The idea of inheritance is simple but powerful: When you want to create a new class and there is already a class that includes some of the code that you want, you can derive your new class from the existing class. In doing this, you can reuse the fields and methods of the existing class without having to write (and debug!) them yourself."*
>
> *"A subclass inherits all the members (fields, methods, and nested classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass can be invoked from the subclass."*